# How to restore /etc/sysctl.conf on Ubuntu 18.04 after overwriting

Tags: files, restore

I was appending an option to `/etc/sysctl.conf` but I accidentally used `>` instead of `>>` so I've overwritten the whole file.

I haven't yet rebooted since it happened.

Is there any way to revert the file back to the original state? I haven't changed anything there since the installation of the OS so hopefully it would suffice to just copy a typical one after install.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew procps` should restore it.

Comment: @nobody This unfortunately does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mine.

```
#
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
# See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
#

#kernel.domainname = example.com

# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
#kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3

##############################################################3
# Functions previously found in netbase
#

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable Spoof protection (reverse-path filter)
# Turn on Source Address Verification in all interfaces to
# prevent some spoofing attacks
#net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1
#net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable TCP/IP SYN cookies
# See http://lwn.net/Articles/277146/
# Note: This may impact IPv6 TCP sessions too
#net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
#  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
#  based on Router Advertisements for this host
#net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1


###################################################################
# Additional settings - these settings can improve the network
# security of the host and prevent against some network attacks
# including spoofing attacks and man in the middle attacks through
# redirection. Some network environments, however, require that these
# settings are disabled so review and enable them as needed.
#
# Do not accept ICMP redirects (prevent MITM attacks)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
# _or_
# Accept ICMP redirects only for gateways listed in our default
# gateway list (enabled by default)
# net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1
#
# Do not send ICMP redirects (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
#
# Do not accept IP source route packets (we are not a router)
#net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
#
# Log Martian Packets
#net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
#

###################################################################
# Magic system request Key
# 0=disable, 1=enable all, >1 bitmask of sysrq functions
# See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html
# for what other values do
#kernel.sysrq=438
```

Funky: it has no active lines. All are comments.
edit: we probably don't use it and use `/etc/sysctl.d/`.

```
See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
```

Comment: It seems that /etc/sysctl.conf is not used so much anymore. For example Arch has deprecated it in 2013 ( https://www.archlinux.org/news/deprecation-of-etcsysctlconf/ ).